# Gambas, Split string by character and add into array

Tags: arrays, string, for-loop, addition, gambas

So I've got this code in Gambas 3 on Debian 8 to split a string into characters, when executed it says, that there

Eingabe and buchstaben are both declared as strings, while buchstaben is an array.

```
Public buchstaben As String[]
Public Eingabe As String



Eingabe = LCase(T1.Text)

For j = 0 To (Len(Eingabe) - 1)
  buchstaben.Add(Mid(Eingabe, i, 1))
  i += 1
Next
```

T1 is a Textbox, which takes strings.

Answer (score 1):

I got the Solution myself now. I need to add

```
buchstaben = New String[]
```

into the function, before I use the array for some reason.

Comment: without the new keyword, your string array won't get initialized, it will only be typed as a String[] but would be Nothing/False. Once you initialize the object, you can use it to Add new items. You could initialize it already during declaration by using `Public buchstaben as New String[]`